# Read multiple csv files and create a excel file with multiple sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, pyspark

I need to read multiple csv files from data lake and write those files into a single .xlsx file with multiple sheets.
This is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df1= spark.read.csv(file1_path)
df_one = df1.toPandas()

df2= spark.read.csv(file2_path)
df_two = df2.toPandas()

with pd.ExcelWriter("path/to/Result_file.xlsx") as writer:
    df_one.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet One", index=False)
    df_two.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet Two", index=False)
```

But Im getting `"No such file or directory "path/to/Result_file.xlsx"`.
I also tried creating an empty Result_file.xlsx file in the data lake. But its not working.
What might be the issue here.

Comment: Does your output directory exist? Pandas probably assume it does. So ensure that it exist, maybe add `os.makedirs('path/to', exist_ok=True)` before calling the `ExcelWriter`.

Comment: Can you check what `os.listdir()` and `os.getcwd()` is returning ?

Answer (score 0):

"No such file or directory" could be due to following issues

1. you do not have directories in place. Use `os.path.isdir("path/to/")` check before opening/writing files - https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir
2. you opened the file in reading mode. use `mode='w'` as suggested in https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html